# Winforms Designer: Modify (and keep) properties in sub objects

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, designer

For a WinForms control, I'd like to move certain settings into a sub object. One of them is a custom class containing all UI Strings, the other a OpenFileDialog:

```
class MyControl: Control
{
  // ...
  private OpenFileDialog m_dlgOpen = new OpenFileDialog();
  public OpenFileDialog DialogOpen
  {
     get { return m_dlgOpen; }
  }
}
```

This adds the sub object to the designer, and allows to edit its properties (e.g. title, default extension, filter). However, the changes are nto added to the `InitalizeComponent` method, so they are lost.

Is it possible to make this properties "persist" in the `InitializeComponent` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell the designer to serialize the object itself:

```
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public OpenFileDialog DialogOpen {
    get { return m_dlgOpen; }
  }
```