# comboBox.SelectedIndex keep getting deleted automatically

Tags: c#

I have a comboBox in my application where I set it to show an item by default. However, when I move something within the Form, VS will automatically remove it from the designer. I have no idea what is going on and if anyone is able to help me fix this issue.

Screenshot:  [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDBhA.jpg)

Comment: Can you send a screenshot? That is very strange.

Comment: Are you binding combobox from code behind or setting default value from UI? If in code behind and on page load, I hope it is in if(!IsPostBack){}

Comment: Updated with screenshot. @ItiTyagi, I'm doing it directly in the designer so im assuming it's code behind.

Comment: Are you editing the designer by hand ?

Comment: Where this code is written? In the event of button click or page load? I asked this earlier as well, Please specify.

Comment: @ItiTyagi the code he posted looks like the generated Winform Intialize Component method that is created when you create a form. The one that states it is auto generated and not to modify with the code editor

Comment: You may need to make a custom control using this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/604365/479512) to serialize it to the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be the generated designer code is corrupted. if you want to fix it create a new form then copy all the controls of the corrupted form into the new one this may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the SelectedIndex property in the form constructor, just after InitializeComponent method call? It's not advised to make changes to the designer code. Moving the control might re-generate the code and discard your changes